# Too much blank space in lower part of title page

Tags: titles

My problem is, that there is too much blank space in the lower part of the title page. Ideally, all elements from the inked_logo down should be better distributed. The last text element ("Things") should be about as far down as a footer would be.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\headheight}{75pt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta} 

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\linespread{1.06}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt plus2pt minus2pt}

\widowpenalty 10000
\clubpenalty 10000

\newcommand{\eat}[1]{}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,noitemsep}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz} % image front
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %header
\pagestyle{fancy} %header

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{header_inked}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

%===========================================================
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Top  Logo
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=0.4\paperheight]{inkedHF}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{75mm}

% Title
\begin{flushleft}
{\LARGE 
  \textbf{Title}\\[0.1cm]
  \textbf{Title again}\\[0.4cm]
  {\scriptsize hello \\ Stand: \today}
}
\end{flushleft} 

\vfill

% Logo Business
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{inked_logo}
\end{figure}


\vfill

% Infos
\begin{flushleft}
{\large Version x.y\newline
hello\newline
Date: \today}
\end{flushleft}

% Bottom 
{\tiny Things}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- But doesn't the question say that there's too much space at the *bottom* of the page?  That would make me thing that the solution is to get rid of that, not do something that would add more space.  (Admittedly, I haven't actually checked this.  My inclination would be to try `\vfillneg`, but I don't think a double-l version exists.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the fancyhdr and \headheight stuff, since the titlepage sets `\pagestyle{empty}` anyway.  Unless you want that huge logo on every page...

The center and Flushleft environments add space above and below each time, which I assume you don't want.  If you want to overlap the bottom of the page, just add some negative `\vspace` at the end.

the tricky part was making the date flush with the bottom of the text area.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta} 

\usepackage{graphicx}


\linespread{1.06}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt plus2pt minus2pt}

\widowpenalty 10000
\clubpenalty 10000

\newcommand{\eat}[1]{}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,noitemsep}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz} % image front

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

%===========================================================
\begin{titlepage}
% Top  Logo
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=0.4\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\dimexpr 0.4\paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\topskip}
\hrule height0pt
\raggedright
{\LARGE 
  \textbf{Title}\\[0.1cm]
  \textbf{Title again}\\[0.4cm]
  {\scriptsize hello \\ Stand: \today}
}
\vfill

% Logo Business
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\vfill

% Infos
\vbox{\raggedright% fills entire width
\large Version x.y\newline
hello\newline
Date: \today}
% Bottom 
\vbox to \footskip{\vfill
\centering
{\tiny Things}}\vspace{-\footskip}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```